# Need help figuring out how to start this inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to make the LHS equal RHS but I don't know where to start. What side I should try to make into the other, or even the first step after I choose the side I'll start on.

> $$(k+1)x^k(x-y) \ge x^{(k+1)} - y^{(k+1)}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is it an equality or an inequality you want to prove? Any hypotheses on $x$ and $y\,$?

Comment: The statement is an inequality but as long as I can prove that they're even which is probably easier, my proof will be complete.

Edit: What do you mean by hypotheses?

Comment: No hypothesis? For a counter-example, take $x=0$, $y=\frac12$.

Comment: Oh sorry, so the actual proof mentions that x and y are real numbers and x is greater than y.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $x^{k+1} - y^{k+1}$ as follows: 
$$x^{k+1} - y^{k+1} = (x-y)(x^{k} + x^{k-1}y + \dots + xy^{k-1} + y^{k}).$$ Now $x-y$ is a common factor on both sides. This could be a starting point to solve the inequality.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So would it turn into (x-y)(1^(k+1))??

Comment: J. Chang  No. It would be something like x^k + x^(k-1) y + ... + y^k. You should try dividing to find that term.

Comment: Wait why did that little equation turn into a long sequence?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1078458)

Comment: @Gibbs I tried to give first step (OP said first step would do)

Comment: @G_S when I reviewed your answer it was much shorter (I can see now you edited it) and did not give any insight, in my opinion.

Comment: @Gibbs Yes. I have edited it a couple of minutes ago. But i still think my previous 'short' answer was enough to start

Comment: @G_S that was my opinion, I do not claim I am right. Anyway your answer could be improved formally. Take a look at my edit: it is a good habit not to start with equations or things in math mode. When brackets are not necessary, do not use them. When it is clear you are writing a product of two numbers, it is not necessary to write $*$, unless you are using a specific notation. Do not start a new line when  not necessary.

Comment: @J. Chang  I can't comment under the question, so asking this here...  Why are you trying to make LHS equal RHS, when it is an inequality?

Comment: because I feel like it's easier than looking at it and proving that one will always be greater than the other.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: 
Use the high-school identity
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}y++x^{n-2}y^2+\dots +y^{n-1})$$
and show each monomial $x^iy^j$ is bounded from above.

*Edit*: you may note the second factor of the factorisation is the sum of all monomials $x^iy^j$ with total degree $i+j=n-1$, so if $y\le$, one has $\;x^iy^j\le x^{i+j}$.

How many of these monomials are there?

Comment: is bounded from above? So then how would I prove that this high-school identity is less than or equal to (k+1) x^k (x−y) ???

Comment: Find an upper bound common to all monomials, taking into account that $x\ge y$.

Comment: Hmm I'm not really understanding this.. What is this identity called again? And if I could maybe get another hint haha?

edit: So what I'm suppose to do is find a limit that the RHS can reach and prove the LHS goes past that?

Comment: @J.Chang: I don't know if the factorisation has a name. It's a generalisation of $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$ and $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$.  I've added another hint.